# Is it possible to view saved wifi passwords without a wireless interface installed (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, passwords, recovery

I have had a network interface installed on a old hard drive, but I can't access them because I don't currently have a adapter installed. Is there any way I can access the passwords?

It keeps responding with "There is no wireless interface on this system" even though I can browse through previously installed network passwords in file explorer.

The drive won't boot on my current company as well. Is there anything I can do to retrieve the passwords?

Comment: The network adapter profiles are in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\  .  The passwords are encrypted so you may not be able to decipher the passwords

Comment: Is there any possible way to? Because I'm aware that folder exists and that's how I knew there were network adapters

Comment: Without any adapter, the above location is about all there is. I don't think there is any easy way to crack the passwords there

Comment: shit. is there any way to make a virtual adapter or something

Comment: I haven’t seen anything like that. Virtual adapters are normally associated with virtual machines

Comment: is it possible to create a network drive and get the password that way? I have another computer with wifi

Comment: I don't think so. You would somehow have to open the file with the Wireless applications and I have not seen that done. Try, but I have not seen it

Comment: Try [WirelessKeyView: Recover lost WEP/WPA key/password stored by Wireless Zero Configuration service](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html). Use the advanced option `/WlansvcFolder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles" ` replacing `C:` with the drive letter of the old drive ... let me know if it works and I will write up as an answer.